# Is there a package offering a command inserting a or an depending on whether a fovel follows?

Tags: tex-core

The question is already the headline:
is there a package which provides a command say \a
which expands to `an` if a spoken vowel follows, else to `a`?
Maybe this is a bit too specific,
because it refers to the English language only.

Comment: The command `\a` is already defined for other things.  Also, this could be problematic, if the following word begins with 'h' or possibly 'y', since in some cases, 'an' may be called for (an honor) and in others, 'a' (a house).

Comment: I'm especially curious how you expect a package to determine whether a spoken vowel follows based on textual input. Even for English, I think this would vary, so you couldn't even use a database of exceptions. If you settled on some standardised formula, I suppose you could do it, but I honestly don't see why anybody would. It would require more typing to use, as well as the effort of developing the code. (Even if `\a` were not already defined, you'd have to type 2-4 characters rather than 1-2 and the content would be less readable.)

Comment: You could define a custom OTF font  feature (using `directlua` command) to do the substitutions, and then activate the feature for a font (using `fontspec` command RawFeature=... option). But input would be `a eel` to typeset `an eel`. Is it for machine translation?

Comment: I fear this is doomed to failure.  Some people use "a" before "historical" and some people use "an".  (And even for the same person, there may be a reason to make a different choice, depending on the circumstances.)  Unless you know much more than you are telling us, there's simply no way to know which to use.

Comment: Even worse, `r` is a vowel in Australian English, `an R` when named, but `a road`, `a rainbow` when used.